# MySQL update a field in a different table after an insert trigger

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a trigger on my orderItem table`(orderId, itemId, quantity)`, to update the field 'quantityInStock, on my item table`(itemId, itemName, itemPrice, primaryImage, itemCategory, quantityInStock)`, whenever an insert occurs. Here is my trigger so far.

```
delimiter $$
drop trigger if exists quantityTrigger $$
create trigger quantityTrigger
after insert on orderItem
for each row begin
update item
set quantityInStock = quantityInStock - new.quantity; 
end $$
delimiter ;
```

The insert statement I am using to test the trigger is below.
Whenever I run the insert statement it changes every row to the same number instead of subtracting the quantityInStock from the quantity ordered.

```
insert into orderItem (orderId, itemId, quantity)
values ('21283', 42, 2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change UPDATE in trigger body to:

```
 update item
 set quantityInStock = quantityInStock - new.quantity; 
 WHERE itemId = new.itemId
```